# Is there a way to cast the type of an element in a numpy array to a type that is written in a seperate string

Tags: python, string, numpy, casting

I need to cast the type of an element in a numpy array to another type that is written in a seperate string(for example "int"). I have an assignment to submit and this was one of the questions.

I tried converting the array using the "astype" method to type "object" and then using "astype" again to convert each of the elements to the required data types(which are not known beforehand but depend on the user input), but you cannot do that since those elements are apparently not of the numpy class anymore.
I also cannot simply type cast to the required type because the data types are only given in strings.
I can't post the code right now since I deleted it and I only found out about the assignment deadline being postponed about 20 minutes ago and it's nighttime here.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't do homework.  Even last-minute homework.  What have you tried?

Comment: `arr1 = arr.astype('int')` is a typical casting  statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert elements of a numpy array to type 'object' using the following:

```
import numpy as np

# Original array
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

# Data type string
type_string = "object"

# Casting the type
new_arr = arr.astype(type_string)

# Display the new array and its data type
print(new_arr)
print(new_arr.dtype)
```